# Creating a Windows 8.1 Tablet App with a Local Database that links back to SQL Server

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-2012, sql-server-ce, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I'm currently working on a project that needs to create a Windows 8.1 tablet application that has a localize database on the tablet. The tablet application must replicate with SQL Server (2012 to be exact). The application needs to be privately deployed out via our servers also.

We really would like to use SQL CE (Compact Edition). The problems are that SQL CE is in deprecation (support will end in 2016) and that WinRT doesn't seem to support SQL CE.

The only other option that we see is using SQLite to create the application local database. I haven't seen much on how to transmit the data back and forth between SQLite and SQL Server 2012.

Is there any other choices in Window 8.1? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to be the app to be a Windows Store app, you can use sqlce. Rob Tiffany has a book that describes how to do that. If it must be a Store app  you must use sqlite. You can use Zumero for Sync in that case.